# Reset of VisualState manager doesn't works

Tags: silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml, visualstatemanager

[How to reset a silverlight control's visual state back to "Normal" on change of visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913086/how-to-reset-a-silverlight-controls-visual-state-back-to-normal-on-change-of)

In the above link, the same thing was discussed, though i have some problem with changing the state.

I have read an article says that if VS is in a state and if we force it to  Goto that state it just returned with true. this is fine but in my cause, am having a button and that button is in a popup. when the button clicks, am closing the popup. while open the popup again seems the mouse hover state is applied till. Though am forcing the Vs for Normal state in popup open event it remains in the old state. While forcing the VS it returns true which means Normal state s applied but UI remains still in the Mouse hover state.

What might be the cause?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisW. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721072/how-to-refresh-the-current-state-with-visualstatemanager]